# Is it possible to develop 2D games in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, 2d-games

I have searched in the web and found very few material on this question. I've heard of Unity 3D and know that there are other tools. But I would like to know if it is possible to develop games in Android Studio? I'm learning Android development and Java, therefore don't want to jump into other language and platforms. However, if it is not efficient way then which one you would advice? Where to start?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can make your own game by using game engine that freely available for Android.

You can use [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). For the tutorial with Android Studio, you can read [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA).

Visit Sample 2D [game with LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/gallery.html)

Comment: Some tutorials to get startet: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/Game-Development-Tutorial-Series.aspx

Comment: @IronMonkey: that link is very useful. I also use tutorials from that site when learning libGDX. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it is possible. But there are some things you should know. Games made without a game engine are usually not as good as you might expect. You define the interaction of the objects in the game with each other with simple codes, but there are collider structures developed for this in game engines. In addition, while adding effects to the game is easy with the game engine, doing this without the game engine is more difficult and does not show a stable working performance.

here are some 2D game tutorials you can do without using a game engine

[game-1](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzLFqCABnRQdzIljUP7xFFBW5neiOMdDM)
[game-2](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsOU6EOcj51e7YesVnTrEtvJDD016p9oS)